# Hadoop and jgit convert between java.io.file and dataoutputstream

Tags: java, hadoop

Hello Im trying to run map reduce jobs on git repositories. I wanted to use a map job to first concurrently clone all repositories to hdfs then do further map reduce jobs on the files. Im running into a problem in that Im not sure how to write the repository files to hdfs. I have seen examples which write individual files but those were outside the mapper and only write single files. The jgit api only exposes a filerepository structure which inherits from file but the hdfs uses paths written as dataoutputstreams. Is there a good way to convert between the two or any examples that do something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The input data to Hadoop Mapper must be on HDFS and not on your local machine or anything other than HDFS. Map-reduce jobs are not meant for migrating data from one place to another. They are used to process huge volumes of data present on HDFS. I am sure that your repository data in not HDFS, and if it is then you wont have needed to perform any operation at first place. So please keep in mind that **map-reduce jobs are used for processing large volumes of data already present on HDFS (Hadoop file system).**